# Unexpected token } error when function is called

Tags: javascript, php, function, syntax-error

When I call this javascript function, I get an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }".

```
function completed(num, title)
{
    if(localStorage.getItem(num + "done" + title) === 'true')
    {
        document.getElementById("completedclick" + title).style.color="#004600";
        document.getElementById("completed" + title).style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, white)";
        colored = false;
        localStorage.setItem(num + "done" + title, false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("completedclick" + title).style.color="#8B1A1A";
        document.getElementById("completed" + title).style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, white)";
        colored = true;
        localStorage.setItem(num + "done" + title, true);
    }

}
```

The function is called by this section of code:

```
<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'>
    <a href='#!' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed('{class1}', ".$passer.")'>
        Completed
    </a>
</div>
```

{class1} gets replaced by the appropriate class when the template is filled out, and $passer is a variable gotten from a database.

Please help, I have tried everything, but can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: `Server Side` | `Client Side` two different Sides!, pretty simple

Comment: The posted code doesn't seem to have any syntax errors, are you sure it's not coming from elsewhere ?

Comment: `onclick='completed('{class1}', ".$passer.")'` - you are attempting to quote single quotes with single quotes here.

Comment: Try onclick='completed("{class1}", ".$passer.")'

Comment: Am I losing it or are there no `<?php ?>` tags anywhere in that html?

Comment: nevermind before, ".$passer." is not correct you want "<?php echo $passer; ?>" @TimLewis your not losing it ... lol ... the only way this will work is if its all being echoed.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix It's 4:53 on a workday before New Years, I was afraid I was lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'>
    <a href='#!' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed('{class1}', ".$passer.")'>
        Completed
    </a>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'><a href='#' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed('".$class1."', ".$passer.")'> Completed </a></div>";
?>
```

From what I can tell anyway. It may need some tweaks, but the general idea is that you're missing all `<?php ?>` tags and trying to use php variables here.

Cheers!

**Edit**

May need some ' or " fixes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having a mixup with single and double quotes.  Try fixing line 2 of this block:

```
<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'>
<a href='#!' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed('{class1}', ".$passer.")'>
    Completed
</a>
</div>
```

to be

```
<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'>
<a href='#!' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed("{class1}", ".$passer.")'>
    Completed
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: no looks like there are no <?php ?> php tags.  Hard to process php without those.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, change this

```
<div class='completed".$done."' id='completed".$passer."'>
    <a href='#!' id='completedclick".$passer."' onclick='completed('{class1}', ".$passer.")'>
        Completed
    </a>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="completed<?php echo $done;?>" id="completed<?php echo $passer;?>">
    <a href="#!" id="completedclick<?php echo $passer;?>" onclick="completed('{class1}', '<?php echo $passer;?>')">
        Completed
    </a>
</div>
```

Mind the quotes as well.  I would also recommend using a `-` between the html and php parts of the classes such as this.

```
class="completed-<?php echo $done;?>"
```

It just reads better that way is all.